# find all elements containing string in a html

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to find all elements in my DOM that have a certain string in them, is it possible? I tried to just iterate through all the elements but it took way too much time

Answer (score 2):

So I found out a way to do that:

Here we use XPath to find all those childless elements which aren't scripts:

```js
var nodes= document.evaluate(".//*[not(self::script) and not(*)]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
```

Now here we get them into an array so we could iterate through them:

```js
var elements = []
var nextNode = nodes.iterateNext();
while(nextHeading) {
  elements.push(nextNode)
  nextNode = nodes.iterateNext();
}
```

And finally, we can run through them and check whether they contain the phrase we are looking for:

```js
var phrase = 'hello world'
for(element of elements) {
  var text = element.innerText
  if( text && text.includes(phrase)) {
    console.log(element)
  }

}
```

----------------------EDIT----------------------

As @Heretic Monkey wisefully noted, I didn't think about a situation in which an element will contain both a text node and another child element

Replacing the first line with the following should do the trick, finding all elements which aren't scripts and contaiting a text node, you could replace the regex inside to already search by a specific term which will also make some of the checks I did earlier irrelevant.

```js
var nodes= document.evaluate(".//*[not(self::script) and matches(text(),'(\w)','i')]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
```

Comment: This answers a different question than that asked. You ask to "find all elements in my DOM that have a certain string in them", but this answer finds all elements whose only children are text nodes that contain a certain string. A subtle but important difference. Consider the following: `<div>hello world<span>we come in peace</span></div>`. Would this script find that `div`?